# counting an unspecified number of integers separated by spaces and finding occurrences of each number in python using dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, integer

Sample Output

```
Enter numbers separated by spaces :1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3

{'1': 2, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1}

1 occurs 2 times

3 occurs 4 times

2 occurs 4 times

5 occurs one time

4 occurs one time
```

So I'm a total newbie at python but I was thinking of starting off like this :

```
d = {}     
user = input("Enter numbers separated by spaces :") 
data = user.split()
```

Except every loop i tried kept saying that I cant convert str() to int(), I'd appreciate any help, I've been staring at this problem for a few hours..this is something I tried for when input is string, trying to implement something similar for dictionary

```
def countdigits (aString):  
  c = 10 * [0]

  for e in aString: 
    c[int(e)] += 1 

  return c 

def main (): 
  n = 0 

  for v in (countdigits(str(input('Enter a string: ')))): 
    if v == 1: 
      print(n, "occurs 1 time")
    elif v!=0:
      print(n, "occurs", v, "times")

    n += 1 

main()
```

I'd like a similar solution to this, for the ouput given (but using dictionaries)

Comment: It would be better if you had included the code that was actually giving you the error.

Comment: @gnibbler yes that is the error I am getting, how'd you know! But how am i going to count each different integer in the input, the loop im using only allows me to count the length of the input, I was thinking count method would allow me to do it but that only counts each element once, also dictionary has no append method so i need to implement a loop that will add how many times each 'key' in the input will occur and that will be assigned a 'value' as given above

Comment: To use a dict, you need to check each time whether the key is already there or not. One way is to use `if e in d:`. In the `else` block put `d[e] = 1`

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
d = {i:data.count(i) for i in data}

for k,v in d:
    print "{0} occurs {1} times\n".format(k,v)
```

or like examples from the comments below:

```
import collections

for a,b in collections.Counter(data).items():
    print "{0} occurs {1} times\n".format(a,b)
```

Comment: `count` scans data once for each element, so this is not particularly efficient

Comment: I figure this will be executed after a list has been created from the split input already.  Not dealing with anything too fancy here, so efficiency isn't a problem, yet.  I'm just going for 1-2 line solutions, lol.

Comment: If you want concise code, the proper thing to use here is `collections.Counter`. Then you can write `for k, v in Counter(data):`

Comment: @gnibbler -- It seems to me that you're missing a `.items` on your comment there.  e.g. `for k,v in Counter(data).items()`.

Comment: @mgilson, I was trying to add it when the edit timed out :(. Stupid edit timeout for comments

Comment: @gnibbler -- well, I couldn't count the number of times I've tried to iterate over a dict as `for k,v in d` only to experience (obvious) unpacking errors... It's quite a forgivable mistake I would say.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess that you were attempting something like this

```
    >>> user = "1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3"
    >>> data = int(user)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3'
```

Something like this:

```
data = user.split()
for item in data:
   number = int(item)
```

should work fine. Note that you probably don't need to convert to `int` for this problem. Leaving the numbers a `str` should work just as well

Answer (score 1):

without importing anything

```
nk="1 2 3 3 2 2 2 1 3 4 5 3"
nk=nk.split()
result={}
for x in nk:
    result.setdefault(x,0)
    result[x]+=1
print result
```

output

```
{'1': 2, '3': 4, '2': 4, '5': 1, '4': 1}
```

Comment: Not sure why some people have an aversion to importing goodies from the standard library, but using `.setdefault` for a sideeffect is not very nice. Better to combine the two lines into `result[x] = result.get(x, 0) + 1`

Comment: My university penalized us for any use of built-in or 3rd party modules, and had us write our own.  Taught bad habits by not using them, despite being more efficient.  They should spend more time going over good practices with them rather than cutting them out all together.